# What is the inductive definition of $n!$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition

Can someone explain the meaning of **inductive** definition of $n!$?

Comment: Can you please say more explicitly?

Comment: I am asking for the meaning of inductive definition with the question I have been asked for reference

Comment: The very first example in the Wikipedia article [Inductive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition) is the factorial function. What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma (n)=n\Gamma (n-1)\,, n\gt0$ and $\Gamma (0)=1$.

So, $\Gamma (n)$ is defined in terms of $n$ and $\Gamma (n-1)$.

Comment: Nice try but $\Gamma(0)=(-1)!$ is undefined. I think you meant $\Gamma(1)=0!=1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in\mathbb N_0$, we define $0!:=1$ and for $n\geq1$, we set $$n!:=(n-1)!\cdot n.$$

Inductive means that we use the value of $(n-1)!$ in order to define the next factorial, which is $n!$.

Answer (score 0):

"Induction", in general, depends upon a statement, depending on a positive integer, n, being true for n= 1 (or 0) and then, if the statement is true for n= k, it is also true for n= k+ 1.

"Defining" something that depends on a positive integer, A(n), "inductively" means defining it for n= 1 (or 0)and then defining A(n+ 1) in terms of A(n).

"n factorial", n!, is define "inductively" by defining 0! to be 1 and then defining (n+1)! to be n(n!).

For example, to find 6! using that definition, I would say that 6!= 6(5!).  Of course to use that I need to first find 5!.  5!= 5(4!).  4!= 4(3!).  3!= 3(2!).  2!= 2(1!).  1!= 1(0!). 0!= 1 (by the first part of the definition) so 1!= 1(1)= 1, 2!= 2(1)= 2, 3!= 3(2)= 6, 4!= 4(6)= 24, 5!= 5(24)= 120, and 6!= 6(120)= 720.